# how to find pine editor coin name and parity?

Tags: pine-script, pine-editor

how to find the parity and coin name in the pine editor, I will use it in the alert() command. I tried using {{exchange}} but it didn't work, is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

`syminfo.tickerid` has everything you need, you just need to use `:` as a delimeter and split the string.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

sym = syminfo.tickerid

getName(_str) =>
    string[] _pair = str.split(_str, ":")
    string[] _exchange = str.split(array.get(_pair, 0), "")  // Index 0
    string[] _asset = str.split(array.get(_pair, 1), "")  // Index 1
    string _ret_exc = array.join(_exchange, "")
    string _ret_ass = array.join(_asset, "")
    [_ret_exc, _ret_ass]

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 3, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    [exchange, asset] = getName(sym)
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = str.tostring(sym))
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 1, text = exchange)
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 2, text = asset)
```

[image]

Comment: does it work in version 4?

Comment: Yes, you just need to adapt v5 to v4 but everything is also available in v4.